# Terminal Ubuntu 20.04 beginner question on how to go further .. thanks for the assistance

Tags: bash, 20.04, gui, .desktop

Downloaded Ubuntu from the Microsoft store and when I click on the GUI I get the terminal. Followed before all the questions so I have (name)@ (computername):~$ I did all the updates through sudo apt update and that worked fine. Which command do I use to get to the Ubuntu desktop? Thanks for the assistance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't install the desktop, but you can discover the wonderful world of shell commands:

[The Linux Command Line, free to download, 550+ pages](https://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu on Windows allows you to use Ubuntu Terminal and run Ubuntu command line utilities including bash, ssh, git, apt and many more.but you can't install ubuntu-desktop through it.
you can only use terminal through it.

for installing ubuntu or dual booting with windows please visit https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot